# $http angular pass object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

Hello how can i pass this object as param in Http with angular?
Because my wcg public void CreateNewAccount(Users us)

```
$scope.RegisterUser = function(){
var us = {
  UserName:$scope.userName,
  Password:$scope.password,
  UserRoleID:null,
  Company:$scope.company,
  Terms:$scope.terms,
  ID:null,
  BuyerID:app.buyerId
};

$http.get(
    app.wcf+'/CreateNewAccount'angular.toJson({us:us}))
    .then(
    function(resp){
     app.Logger(resp.data);
    },
    function(err){
      app.Logger(err);
})};
```

Comment: why are you doing a `$get` with this - shouldn't it be a post?

Comment: could be but on wcf its Get so atm will be get just how to send this object or $get cannot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass your object as `params` in to the config of the `$http.get(url, config)` method.

```
$http.get(app.wcf + '/CreateNewAccount', {params: us})
  .then(function(resp){
     app.Logger(resp.data);
  },
  function(err){
    app.Logger(err);
})};
```

That said, you shouldn't be passing this data as a `GET` request, especially not with a username and password in the query string.

Comment: Thx :) just testing new platform.

Comment: Tom Could you modify this for post request?

Comment: @Alex, `$http.post(app.wcf + '/CreateNewAccount', us).then(...)`

Answer (score 1):

For `get`, you should use params:

```
$http({method:'GET', url:'url', params:us})
```

Comment: $http({method:'GET', url:app.wcf+'/CreateNewAccount', params:us}).then

correct?:)

Comment: How to make post with data?:)

Comment: If you want to do a post, that would be $http({method:'POST', url:'url', data: us});

Comment: could you look why its not POST but OPTIONS?

Answer (score -1):

I'm getting this it seams to call OPTIONS 
`Remote Address:192.168.58.182:80
Request URL:http://192.168.58.182/ESService/ESService.svc/CreateNewAccount
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,pl;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:192.168.58.182
Origin:http://localhost:8100
Referer:http://localhost:8100/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.93 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST,GET,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:1728000
Allow:POST
Content-Length:1565
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 30 Jan 2015 14:10:34 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET`